# Encode a struct with solidity

Tags: solidity, struct, bytes, abiencoderv2

Is it possible to encode a struct in Solidity without serializing each variable separately?

Something like:

```js
struct MyStruct {
   uint x;
   uint y;
}

MyStruct storage myStruct = MyStruct({
   x: 11,
   y: 12
});

bytes memory data = abi.encode(myStruct, (MyStruct));
```

Or in assembly?

Comment: What do you want to do with the encoded data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to store this on your contract, solidity structs are already stored encoded in storage.

Just define a data member as struct and assign values, it will be properly encoded.

In case you want to send this as a function parameter, you can just pass the struct (if that's the input type) and it will also be encoded properly.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to encode a struct is to spread it out while encoding.

I.e.:

```
abi.encode(MyStruct.x, MyStruct.y);
```

Make sure to pass the parameters in the right order so that you get the right values when you're retrieving the data off-chain and decoding it.